# Parsing the command line parameters via getopt in C

Tags: c, getopt

Trying to parse the command line arguments and then print them out... How could I do this using getopt?

I need getopt for a bases for later development of the code/.

```
 #include <ctype.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main (int argc, char **argv)
 {
     char *cvalue = NULL;
     int c;

     while ((c = getopt (argc, argv, "n1n2n3n4c:")) != -1)              
         switch (c):
             case n1:
             case n2:
             case n3:
             case n4:
                 for(int i=0; i<argc;i++)
                 {
                     printf("Option: d%", argv[i]);
                 }
             default: break;


     printf ("n1flag = %d, n2flag = %d, n3flag = %d, n4flag = %d cvalue = %s\n",
              n1flag, n2flag, n3flag, n4flag, cvalue);

     for (index = optind; index < argc; index++)
         printf ("Non-option argument %s\n", argv[index]);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You can also take a look at the [GNU C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

Comment: As an addendum to Brian's answer, if you want -nX options, you will use a single -n option that requires an argument, and validate the argument you receive (e.g. optarg is "5" when your option is 'n', but -n5 isn't valid). Otherwise, consider using getopt_long_only - a GNU function created for options in the style required by the X Window System (e.g. "-display :X.Y" would be the option -display, and :X.Y would be the option argument). If that still doesn't work for you, perhaps you might create your own argument parser.

Answer (score 1):

getopt uses single characters as options, you cannot therefore define n1, n2, n3, n4, etc. you instead need to give them unique single characters instead.

See the getopt man pages: http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt